# Is there a software which will let me save an album view of graphic files?

Tags: image-viewer

The short version:

Is there any desktop application which will load hundreds of images and show them in a simple grid, let me filter them, and save the view in a common format? I think something like a view-saving photo workflow software will be best for my purpose, but would accept other solutions.

---

The background:

Our team did some empirical research, and I evaluated the data. I ran more than 3800 instances of a parametrized evaluation, and the result of each can be expressed as a single image. Now we want to look at the images and see which results are good, etc.

I think that a view like that of photo workflow software would be best. It would show all the pictures in a simple grid, and I could tag each image with the parameter used, and filter the view to see only the images for certain parameters. The option to easily zoom all the pictures at once would come handy too.

But my prof certainly won't install and learn a photo workflow software on her computer, so whenever I have a meaningful view, I should be able to export it into a format she can open with whatever she has (office package, pdf viewer, browser). Screenshots are out of question, as a view can scroll over dozens of screens. And I don't know of a photo workflow software which can do that. I know I could save a local html copy of the album view of an online photo manager like Picassa, but even if the links to the pictures still work, this data is too business-critical for us to be uploaded to some hoster, even if he offers private albums.

Platform should be Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com) certainly has album sharing options. See if that has features (not got time and don't use it enough myself to check! Sorry!) :)